# Android : is it safe to create a View and a Handler in a worker thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

The android docs states that :

> > The Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread.

**My first question** is : is it safe to go against this *rule/advice* by creating a View in a worker thread, then using a handler to attach it to the window. (See code below to illustrate what I mean).

It seems OK, because I can't see any situation where 2 threads modify the view at the same time. Do I miss something ?

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout rootLayout;
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rootLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        myThread.start();
    }

    private Thread myThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final TextView textView = new TextView(DemoActivity.this);
            textView.setText("I'm a TextView created in a worker Thread");
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        rootLayout.addView(textView);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

**My second question** is more about the thread creating the Handler:

Is it OK to create the Handler in the worker thread itself? (see code below)

Is there a risk of memory leak ?

```
   private Thread myOtherThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final TextView textView = new TextView(DemoActivity.this);
            textView.setText("I'm a TextView created in a worker Thread");
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        rootLayout.addView(textView);
                }
            });

            //just to illustrate that the thread don't terminate immediately
            //but it don't touch the textView anymore.
            while(true){  
                doStuff();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: 2. It's okay because you specified Looper in Handler constructor implicitly. By default it tries to get default Looper for the thread and since you thread doesn't have one, it will crash.

Comment: 1. It may be safe, depends on View implementation. If the View creates handlers using default constructor then it will be unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, as said, it is not safe.

Being not safe, Android exposes a single thread model that ensures UI is not modified by different threads at the same time. It is done on purpose to avoid such issues.

1. Yes I think it is okay, because it is another thread :)

Also take a look at [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: Can you elaborate on point 1 ? Do you see a situation where the UI thread and the worker thread modify the textView at the same time. (all modifications on textView are done before attaching it to the window)

Comment: I just tried test code and it didn't crashed. My bet it's safe. While View is just created, not attached to a parent, nobody will modify it at the same time.

Comment: But it still feels like a bad design and potentially can crash depending on particular View implementaton.

Comment: @shkschneider I created a TextView in a separate thread, assigned a text to it and then added it to an Activity via Handler.

Comment: It can work, it is just not safe. Meaning in can crash. It is simply a bad design and you should respect the single thread for UI aspect of Android and not try to avoid it, because it will eventually crash.

Comment: Sorry, but what you are saying is confusing. *UI-toolkit is not thread-safe* means that there is no mechanism preventing you to manipulate the UI-components from 2 distinct threads simultaneously BUT if you do it : you will probably get unexpected behavior.

Comment: That is what I meant (sorry if that was confusingly said).

Comment: If you create a View in a worker thread, then events posted to it will be delivered in the worker thread rather than the UI thread, so the View will not be able to update itself reliably.